# Tracert second hop 0.0.0.0

Tags: networking

So I am having trouble knowing what's going why my second hop is my own pc. I tried to search about it but got nowhere. It also gets laggy and slow down my internet connection causing disruptions.

```
    Tracing route to google.com [172.217.22.131]
    over a maximum of 30 hops:

      1    10 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1 
      2     6 ms     8 ms     7 ms  MyPC [0.0.0.0]
      3    20 ms    23 ms    23 ms  172.19.132.146
```

Edit 1: I am using Windows 10 x64

```
Pinging MyPC [192.168.1.16] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.16: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.16:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: What OS? If Windows, please [edit] question with output of `ping -a mypc -n 1`